# How to transform using the term-by-term integration theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

## Question

The measure $\mu$ is defined on the measurable space $(\mathbb{N},2^\mathbb{N})$ as follows.
$$
\mu(A) := \sum_{k\in A} \frac{1}{k}
$$

The following equality follows when term-by-term integration is used.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f_n(k)}{k} \overset{?}{=} \int_\mathbb{N} f_n d\mu
$$

I don't understand the transformation of the question mark equals sign.

## What I know

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f_n(k)}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{N} \cdots =  \int_\mathbb{N} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \cdots = \int_\mathbb{N} f_n d\mu
$$

I also note the contents of $f_n$ just in case this transformation might depend on $f_n$:
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{\sin{(n(x-a))}}{n(x-a)},\ a\in\mathbb{R}, \frac{\sin{0}}{0} = 1.
$$

Comment: What's $f_n$? why not just write $f$?

Comment: @Yanko This is because the definition of $f(x)$ includes $n$. Please refer to the $f_n(x)$ definition of "What I know"

Comment: Alright, so let me see if I understand. Basically you just ask why is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k} = \int_{\mathbb{N}} f d\mu$ for all $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$? (and then you take $f=f_n$)

Comment: Also I assume that when you say "the following transformations follow" you mean the following **equality** follow?

Comment: $\int g\,d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k g(k)$ **if** $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\left\lvert g(k)\right\rvert<\infty$. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1kg(k)$ is conditionally convergent, then $\int g\,d\mu$ doesn't exist, nor can you really make sense of it.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oh right. Well in that case we need to be even more careful with what the question really is :-)

Comment: @Yanko Ah, was that not the question?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Possibly, I did not understand it until you came so...

Comment: @Yanko That’ correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \left|\frac{f(k)}{k}\right| < +\infty$, we prove the equality. It is known otherwise the counting measure integration is not well-defined.

Start off with a characteristic function: $\chi_A$ with $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Then we indeed have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} \chi_{A} \,d\mu = \mu(A \cap \mathbb{N}) = \sum_{k \in A \cap \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{\chi_A(k)}{k}.
$$
This implies the same holds for nonnegative simple functions $s: \mathbb{N} \to [0, +\infty)$:
$$
\int_\mathbb{N} s \,d\mu = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{s(k)}{k}.
$$
Moving onto Nonnegative functions $g: \mathbb{N} \to [0, +\infty)$ through upward approximation of simple functions and Monotone Convergence:
$$
\int_\mathbb{N} g \,d\mu = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{g(k)}{k}.
$$
For general functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbf{R}$, separate it into $f = f^+ - f^-$, where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$. Then as the series $\sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k}$ is absolutely convergence, we have
$$
\int_\mathbb{N} f \,d\mu = \int_\mathbb{N} f^+ \,d\mu - \int_\mathbb{N} f^- \,d\mu = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{f^+(k)}{k} - \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{f^-(k)}{k} = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{f^+(k) - f^-(k)}{k} = \sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k}.
$$